# Can I use bootstrap form class outside form tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This question is about best practice. Can I use `form-horizontal` class  on a `<div>` element. I am trying to use style that these form class provides but I don't want to use form tag.

Is it good practice ?

```
<div class="form-horizontal" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>    
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If im correct the `form-horizontal` contains `CSS`? And you want to use other customized `CSS`?

Comment: I want to use styling provided by these classes but don't want to use form tag. The above piece of code works fine. But wanted to know if this is good practice or not ?

Comment: If you want to use other styling you need to look into the `CSS` file. This is good practice, you can use other `CSS` styling and you can create your own custom made ones. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No. I just wanted to know if above piece of good is correct or not. Correct meaning good practice or not